# Python problem IndentationError: expected an indented block

Tags: python

**My program**

```
#import time to sleep
import time
import os
import datetime

print("1 = List all files")
print("2 = Select file")
print("3 = Delete selected")
print("4 = Set path")

# Selection
print(" ")
sel = int(input("Enter choice: "))
print(" ")

if sel == 1:

if sel == 2:

if sel == 3:

if sel == 4:
```

It’s saying "IndentationError: expected an indented block" on the *second* ***if***.
I’m starting with Python, and everything helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your *if* block does not do anything, you should use a special "pass" word:

```
#import time to sleep
import time
import os
import datetime

print("1 = List all files")
print("2 = Select file")
print("3 = Delete selected")
print("4 = Set path")

#selection
print(" ")
sel = int(input("Enter choice: "))
print(" ")

if sel == 1:
    pass
if sel == 2:
    pass
if sel == 3:
    pass
if sel == 4:
    pass
```

Comment: Please do not answer questions like this that do not even come close to meeting the minimum standards described in [ask].

Comment: Im sorry I was busy